# Как распасрить дату формата /Date(1111111111111+0800)/

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста. С сервера приходит поле Дата с таким форматом: /Date(1556504373000+0800)/ . Как его распарсить в формат дд.мм.гггг или мм?